# Page jumping on a slight scroll in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a page jump recorded by the following code in the console Chrome

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
console.log( $(this).scrollTop() );
});
```

Below are the positions recorded when the down arrow key is slightly pressed and you can see it jumps from 0 to 38 and back to 1.

```
0.6666666865348816
38
1.3333333730697632
0
```

Is there a way to force prevent this as i can't figure out what is causing this?